# Efficient filter, map, and reduce operation on a long list in Python

Tags: python, numpy, filter, list-comprehension, generator

There is a list (price_list) of 10 million numbers as a price in range (0-100). I would like to do the following operations consequently:

1. Filter the list with this condition (list_item < 30)
2. Multiply each list_item with a fixed number (mapping)
3. compute the sum of all elements (reduce)

Here is the sample code:

> ```
> import time
> import numpy as np
> from functools import reduce
>
> with open('price_list.txt') as f:
>     price_list = f.read().split('\n')
>     
> price_list = np.array(price_list).astype(int)  # convert string to int
> ```

I tried following options:

- Using NumPy module (0.1069948673248291 seconds): `total =  np.sum(price_list[price_list < 30] * 1.05)`
- Using brute force loop (9.485718965530396 seconds)
- Using filter, map, and reduce functions (10.078220844268799 seconds): `total =  reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,map(lambda x: x * 1.05, filter(lambda x: x < 30, price_list)) )`
- Using list comprehension (8.609008073806763 seconds): `total= sum([x * 1.05 for x in price_list if x <30])`
- Using generator (8.780538320541382 seconds): `total= sum((x * 1.05 for x in price_list if x <30))`

It is obvious that the NumPy module is significantly fast in these operations. Is there any alternative solution for running this code faster using Python built-in functions and capabilities?

Comment: May you explain the reason?

Comment: How many *different* prices are there?

Comment: And what's the *range* of the prices (smallest, largest)?

Comment: 10 million items in range (1-99)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The Numpy is fast in the calculation but it is inefficient in converting the string list to an int list

### Tips:

1. Use the Numpay array with NumPy functions only, using the Numpay data structure with pythonic functins is inefficient and vice-versa
2. Counter in some cases (when doing the conversion inside the counter) is the fastest among the Pythonic methods
3. To get the benefit of Numpy efficiency do the list conversion with python.

To better compare the results, the running time can be divided into three categories for this problem:

1. Time for reading from file (same for all tries)
2. Time to convert the string list into an int list (different for python list and numpy array)
3. Time to calculation (varies for different methods)

This separation is required to clearly show the efficiency of python list vs NumPy array.
Having a look to the code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter


def print_result(total_price, duration, method):
    print('{method:<35s} {0:>20.3f} (sec), total_price={1:<10.3f}'
          .format(duration, total_price, method=method))


start = time.time()
with open('price_list.txt') as f:
    price_list = f.read().split('\n')
print('Duration for reading from file: {0:<50.3f}'.format(time.time() - start))

start = time.time()
np_price_array = np.array(price_list).astype(int)  # uing numpy array
print('Duration for converting to numpy int array: {0:<50.3f}'.format(
    time.time() - start))

start = time.time()
price_list = list(map(int, price_list))
print('Duration for converting to python int list: {0:<50.3f}'.format(
    time.time() - start))

start = time.time()    
total_price = np.sum(np_price_array[np_price_array < 30] * 1.05)
print_result(total_price, time.time() - start, "NumPy function (numpy array)")

start = time.time()
total_price = sum([x for x in np_price_array if x < 30])*1.05
print_result(total_price, time.time() - start,
             "List comprehension (numpy array)")


start = time.time()
total_price = sum((x for x in price_list if x < 30))*1.05
print_result(total_price, time.time() - start, "List generator (Python list)")

start = time.time()
total_price = sum([x for x in price_list if x < 30])*1.05
print_result(total_price, time.time() - start,
             "List comprehension (Python list)")

start = time.time()
total_price = sum([float(x[0]) * float(x[1])
                  for x in Counter(price_list).items() if x[0] < 30]) * 1.05
print_result(total_price, time.time() - start, "Counter (Python list)")

start = time.time()
total_price = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x+y, filter(lambda x: x < 30, price_list)) * 1.05
print_result(total_price, time.time() - start, "functions (Python list)")
```

Following chart is as the result of the code output:

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to see my Counter solution in there somehow as well (since it's faster).

Comment: You forgot to set `start` for the numpy-on-numpy calculation, making it look much slower than it is.

Comment: mozway's solution with `np.loadtxt` would also be interesting, both the old slow one and the new fast one (as mentioned by Michael under my answer).

Comment: @Kelly Bundy. Very nice code I see. I checked that the Counter in some runs is the fastest but not in all, I don't know why?! we my check the aggregated average result of more independent runs.

Comment: Well, their data has lots of duplicates, so my way of using a Counter very much reduces the number of str-to-int conversions, from 10 million to ~100. Maybe counting strings takes longer than counting ints (I didn't check), but overall it seems much faster. In my own test it was so much faster that I'd expect it to be faster *every time*. What numbers did you put into your file?

Comment: I will share my dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Benchmark with three new solutions (starting from a list of strings as the one you got from your file):

```
 4.1 s  original_numpy
11.6 s  original_listcomp
 4.8 s  better_listcomp
 1.7 s  even_better_listcomp
 0.6 s  counter
```

`better_listcomp`'s only difference to yours is that I added `.tolist()`, so that `price_list` is actually a list and Python gets to work with Python ints instead NumPy ints, which is much faster. (Calling an array a list was really mislabeling).

`even_better_listcomp` goes a step further, never even going through NumPy at all. (And it multiplies with 1.05 just *once*, *after* adding.)

`counter` goes even further, delaying the conversion  from string to int until after counting the price strings.

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVPLboMwELzzFXuLXbkImvYStad8RlQhl5rUCn7INlFQ1W@nXkMU8jhUSuFiVrMzs97B9uHL6OUwfIoGPkQIwlWt9KE2yhLrZC3SJ11lEJ9TAd5A25w7x/s5LOc@9FYQqeM5GKwRmlqdCJ3T4DtFNgd4gDIvXqAxDg4g9ZxYNrH0CsvinWYZuhJ7oau/WfPRluIW5dmM85aDc2k/l53cjeq16XRUvhac0UU5ssO2faLdsXiIzOvr1lwGoTyhKDd1oea5pHFyKzVvK90p29@5hbnXiEW7J@RmRpVmn3zQCyP/lIg7gtB0usbtnt8Nu7bILlPMbgaIHRcbqZ1REKQSIJU1LqRzNp2TDHAfZxuBtWlbUQdptD/i10ems8tI2ccw@uAYOK63gpQMyqKgNO27wDfKx9ErHH2EPE0Xi2XMCKTJxxo@SI0Gp98qQcll1KfNxIA1i@8RDY@xdfWcl80PeFgwaPKq0lyJqqLZCU@H4Rc)):

```
def better_listcomp(price_list):
    price_list = np.array(price_list).astype(int).tolist()
    return sum([x * 1.05 for x in price_list if x < 30])

def even_better_listcomp(price_list):
    prices = map(int, price_list)
    return sum([x for x in prices if x < 30]) * 1.05

def counter(price_list):
    return sum(int(k) * v for k, v in Counter(price_list).items() if int(k) < 30) * 1.05

def original_numpy(price_list):
    price_list = np.array(price_list).astype(int)
    return np.sum(price_list[price_list < 30] * 1.05)

def original_listcomp(price_list):
    price_list = np.array(price_list).astype(int)
    return sum([x * 1.05 for x in price_list if x < 30])

funcs = original_numpy, original_listcomp, better_listcomp, even_better_listcomp, counter

from time import time
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

price_list = list(map(str, range(1, 100))) * 101010

for _ in range(2):
    for f in funcs:
        t = time()
        f(price_list)
        print(f'{time() - t :4.1f} s ', f.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Yes, why? Like I said, like the one they got from their file (with their `f.read().split('\n')`).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Maybe even better would be to start with a *file*, but then I'd first like to know the format of the file (i.e., what whitespace they have). And if I remember correctly (from a year or two ago), NumPy has some file reading functions but they're very slow.

Comment: >99% of the time is spent to convert the `list` in  *original_numpy*, not using the (recently improved) native `numpy` function to load data. But that would also skew the comparison.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Yes, that's one reason my last two solutions don't do that conversion. What NumPy function and how recently was it improved? I'm only on a phone, limited by what tio.run has to offer.

Comment: About a [month ago](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.23.0-notes.html#:~:text=Implementation%20of%20loadtxt%20in%20C%2C%20greatly%20improving%20its%20performance.)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Ah, then tio certainly doesn't have that yet. Anyway, I'll probably leave it at this, as they asked for fast non-NumPy alternatives, and I think my `counter` solution is about as good as that gets (much faster than theirs and doesn't even need the array).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no**.

Numpy uses vectorised version of math operations wherever it can.
It means that if you have a `nd.array` of values, it can fit them into the SIMD registers of procesors. This means, that it can multiply tuples of numbers simultaneously (4, 8 or 16 at the same time depending on the SIMD version your processor supports.

Since Python is an interpreted language, you don't really have any alternatives. You would have to manually code procedures in a language that has access to the low level SIMD/AVX instructions of your processor and wrap it in the python API... which is exactly what NumPy is.

Comment: Usually *vectorized* has a different meaning in `numpy`: using a native function call to iterate over a contiguous memory block. Coincidentally in a recent [PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/21001), SIMD instructions (the common meaning of `vectorized`) were added to `sum` integer types. So, @mozway's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73185238/14277722) would use SIMD, while OP's solution won't, but is still a *vectorized* `numpy` function. The running time is mostly spent gathering and creating a new array from boolean indices.

Comment: The primary meaning of 'vectorize' in numpy is to use compiled numpy methods, as opposed to interpreted loops.  The use of low level SIMD vectorization is more of a processor and compiler implementation.  It may be easier to use that with the numpy code, but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is written in C with efficient routines specialized for vectorial operations on numeric data.

Another particularity is that the data is stored in specialized containers (arrays) that optimize memory access.

In your case you could use:

```
import numpy as np

# load the data directly as numpy array
a = np.loadtxt('price_list.txt', dtype=np.int64)

# filter, sum, multiply
out = (a[a<30]).sum()*1.05
```

Comment: But the reduce() functions in Python like as many other functions also is written in C for better efficiency if this is the only reason.
https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20Python's%20reduce(),still%20is%20in%20Python%202.

Comment: Yes, but the operations are not vectorial, reduce will be looping over the python objects one after the other while numpy will loop internally in C.

Comment: @csmaster - `reduce` is written in C but it is still working with python `int` objects and not a hardware level integer. "Multiply" means calling `int.__mul__` and incurring the cost of python's object overhead instead of numpy's use of native operations on machine words.